# передать контекст в шаблон без api

Tags: django, reactjs

есть views которая парсит данные и возвращает их в шаблон контекстом, как мне отдать на фронт эти данные используя reactjs для frontend, без api? возможно ли это?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В джанговском шаблоне написать что-то вроде

```
<script>
   window.yourData = {...}
</script>
```

И на стороне фронта с этой переменной уже можно будет работать, не важно реакт там будет или нет.

Только желательно обернуть ваш скрипт в специальный тег, чтобы шаблонизатор воспринимал содержимое буквально, без изменений. По аналогии с тегом literal в smarty.